# Date not getting sorted properly

Tags: php, javascript, date, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Date not getting sorted in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519463/date-not-getting-sorted-in-javascript)

I have used 24\jan\2012 format for a table of dates. Table entries are like 24/jan/1978 30/feb/2011 etc. I can't change format of date as database has more than 1000 entries. The problem with code is I am specifying date which usual format is 24/3/1956 etc.

I don't know how to specify date format for 21/nov/2011 etc.kindly help.  Other table fields such as name and all are getting sorted. What to do ?

My code is:

```
<th class="table-sortable">Date table-filterable</th>
```

this is written inside php print statement.Only the 23 5 etc are getting sorted not jan mar etc.

Comment: What are you using to sort the table - PHP or JavaScript? There are lots of solutions, and they're all different.

Comment: Q: What is the underlying database?

Comment: how can you sort 24\jan\2012 in 24/jan/1978 format??

Answer (score 0):

*If* my understanding is correct, I think you're asking how to parse the month as an insertable value - which means this isn't really about sorting (alphabetically), and more about sorting (parsing).

If that's the case, then I propose the following solution.

```
$data = '30/Feb/2012';               // non-existent date, by the way
$dateArray = explode('/', $data);    // array('30', 'Feb', '2012')
$month = $dateArray[1];              // 'Feb'
$abbreviations = array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', ...);
$key = array_search($month, $abbreviations);
$numericalMonth = $key + 1;
```

And that would give you a month ranging from 1 to 12, which can then be sorted.

...If I understand your question correctly.

**edit**

If you wish to sort this as *output*, then you can reformat this:

```
$newDate = implode('/', array($dateArray[0], $numericalMonth, $dateArray[2]));
```

All of this being said, it must also be noted that a much more concise method to parse your data is to use the `strtotime()` and `date()` functions.

Comment: Mzhang :exactly u have read my mind. Thank you :) and all others who have replied thanks a lot.am using oracle database.

Comment: Mzhang : can you please show me strtotime and date function example ?pls. To convert to normal format. Thanks in advance